# Visual Studio 2012 C#.NET MVC 4 and SQL Database with Entity Framework and maybe Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just been on a course that talked about the advantages of using MVC 4 in C#.NET alongside using Entity framework to create object representations of a SQL database and using Unity to create instances of objects etc...

Problem is, It was very much an overview rather than a - step one.. create a project, step 2, download sql and set it up, create a database and do a dance. step 3, click here and type here to create an entity model of that db... etc etc.

Does anyone know any books out at the moment that make this entire subject easy to pick up... Once I know how to set up a SQL server and attach the entity framework (without using the buggy visual studio code generator that doesn't help me one bit), I might be able to make a flipping website ^_^...

P.S, I know PHP, JavaScript, Java, C++ very well... That means I know jack doodle about C# and C# libraries. This book would be a basic beginner tutorial thingy...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: [What is wrong with the huge amount of information on `asp.net`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)? If you don't mind the fact that it's MVC3 and uses StructureMap instead of Unity, there's [several hours of guided video tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight) available.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040 and http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-ASP-NET-Dino-Esposito/dp/0735643385 - both these authors tend to write good, usable books.

Comment: Bro, this is sweet as... i'll see how basic it is to understand.. I'm pretty noob, In fact I've only just brushed against the nipple of .net, and Microsoft SQL manager, let alone working with the data in an MVC and entity manner. it's bringing me out in some kind of rash!

Comment: @TiesonT., shall I ignore the "pro" word then? Coz I think there is a mvc 4 one of the same book? http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Professional-Apress/dp/1430242361

Comment: @JamesT Either one. MVC4 just adds some nice features like bundling and whatnot, so anything you learn in the MVC3 book is applicable to MVC4. Anything by Adam Freeman is good, really.

Comment: @TiesonT. last 2 questions. I promise :). 1) Do you know if it guides you through setting up Microsoft SQL as a data source... (2) I assume this book is fine for Visual Studio 2012 Express and SQL express?

Comment: I put in an order regardless, I hope it's what I was after. Thanks for the help buddoss!

Comment: @JamesT I'm not personally familiar with either book, but I've read other Freeman books, so that's where my recommendation comes from. As for the questions, (1) if you mean how to generate a data model from a database, then yes, and (2) parts of the book will be incompatible with the Express editions (like TDD), but they generally warn you when/where those problems are. FWIW, there are Professional versions available at DreamSpark (https://www.dreamspark.com/) if you're a student.

Comment: I'm just a guy looking to waste some time... I'm a professional web developer in PHP/MySQL and want to get into C#.NET because I know it's pretty sick and after doing lots of DirectX games as a personal hobby, I have a funny feeling that i'm gnna like using more Microsoft products. So i'm stuck with express until I grow some bells(ding dong) and fork out for the VS2012 pro, awww yea. First site I want to build is to update some legacy information site that's making a few pennies here and there... a warm up project lets say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 (Professional Apress)

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Professional-Apress/dp/1430242361](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361)

this series is great.

1. Nice step-by-step process to creating an app
2. Great history of .NET development and the MVC frameworks
3. Best overview of the framework. Good coverage explaining just enough about controller, Views, EF, Helpers, Web API.

Comment: Cheers bro, I bought the book yesterday and your recommendation has made me even more excited :D

Comment: Good luck buddy. I hope you enjoy it as much as I do.

Comment: Just finished this book. It was exactly what I was looking for.. I LOVE the repository models and ninject/moq stuff!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a book but you might want to take a look at the [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) sample project. It uses MVC and Entity Framework. Not unity though, but they do have a rather lengthy PDF describing how the sample site was made.

Comment: MVC music store is a classic up there with Nerd Dinner and Twitter as classic examples.

Comment: Oh great, I'm going to absorb this

Comment: This was tremendously helpful. Thank you